# Why is emberjs throwing an error when receiving an error message from the server?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to ember, and this is probably something very simple I'm missing.  The "422 (Unprocessable Entity)" are something I'm setting up on the server side, and not part of a library, so if it needs to be something different for a 422, I couldn't find the docs.

Browser is chrome.  Server side is Hunchentoot.

This is the error shown on the chrome console:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/users 422 (Unprocessable Entity) jquery.js:8706
send jquery.js:8706
x.extend.ajax jquery.js:8136
(anonymous function) ember-data-1.0.0-beta.8.js:2016
invokeResolver ember-1.5.1.js:9646
Promise ember-1.5.1.js:9632
Adapter.extend.ajax ember-data-1.0.0-beta.8.js:2005
Adapter.extend.createRecord ember-data-1.0.0-beta.8.js:1794
_commit ember-data-1.0.0-beta.8.js:11343
(anonymous function) ember-data-1.0.0-beta.8.js:10516
Ember.EnumerableUtils.forEach ember-1.5.1.js:1932
Ember.Object.extend.flushPendingSave ember-data-1.0.0-beta.8.js:10501
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember-1.5.1.js:6127
Backburner.end ember-1.5.1.js:6215
Backburner.run ember-1.5.1.js:6254
Ember.run ember-1.5.1.js:6664
handleRegisteredAction ember-1.5.1.js:38510
(anonymous function) ember-1.5.1.js:22259
x.event.dispatch jquery.js:5095
v.handle jquery.js:4766
```

This is the json that's being returned:

```
{"errors" : { "username" : ["Username exists"]}}
```

The adapter:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter
```

Here's the model, the alert is never called:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  password: DS.attr('string'),
  becameInvalid: function( model) {
    alert('Whoops')
  }
})
```

The signup controller:

```
App.SignupController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  confirm_password: "",

  actions: {
    signup: function() {
      var user = this.get('model')
      var self = this
      user.save().then( function( post) {
        self.transitionToRoute('/tasks', post)
      })    
    }
  }
})
```

The router:

```
App.SignupRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('user')
  }
})
```

Comment: If you are using Google Chrome. That error is thrown by Chrome on console

Comment: Which adapter are you using?

Comment: Is your request going to a rails server?

Comment: Yes it's chrome.  I'm using DS.RESTAdapter.  Updated the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this to the adapter in my code:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajaxError: function(jqXHR) {
    var error = this._super(jqXHR);

    if (jqXHR && jqXHR.status === 422) {
        var jsonErrors = Ember.$.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText)["errors"];

        return new DS.InvalidError(jsonErrors);
    } else {
        return error;
    }
  }
});
```

Very frustrating

Comment: I feel your pain, Ember Data is still beta though, I'd avoid using it until it's actually had a release build.  Until then the documentation will be sparse and the implementation will be constantly changing (especially the relationship management).  Ember works perfectly fine without it.

Comment: Additionally the errors portion works out of the box with the ActiveModelAdapter (not that that is mentioned on the errors page of the documentation)